# Unity3d: How to map real-world coordinates to scene coordinates?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have a physical (real-world) camera and a Unity3d Scene. I want to map the physical camera coordinate system to the virtual scene, 1:1.

For example, imagine the physical camera is pointed at the sky and an aircraft flies overhead. I want to have the physical aircraft appear in my virtual environment, at the correct location. I can get the ADS-B data (which describes position and altitude of the aircraft) and a generic 3D aircraft model. I can import that 3D aircraft model into my scene, but how do I know where to put it and at which height in the scene? And when I move the physical camera, I want the virtual camera to move in the same way.

Put another way, if you wanted to recreate the Earth (ignoring all textures, lighting, etc.) in Unity3D, how would you ensure that objects in the physical world appear in the same location as in your virtual Earth?

How can I do this?

Comment: "When I move the physical camera, I want the movement to exactly correspond to the movement in the 3D scene" -> if you just translate the camera, that is just what happens, so I think I dont understand the question. Maybe a picture or diagram helps to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you asking "I have no way to track the real camera in the real world. How do I do this?"

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I want a pixel on my physical camera to correspond to a pixel in my virtual environment. Imagine you had a camera pointed at the sky and an aircraft was flying overhead. You get the transponder data (i.e., via ADS-B) - this tells you the position of the aircraft and its altitude. Now imagine you have a generic 3d airplane. You can easily add the generic aircraft to your scene, but where should you put it? How would you map the physical world view to the virtual one? Your physical camera movements should correspond to the movements in the virtual world.

Comment: are you asking for [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a built-in `LocationService` class to determine your location on the globe. Then there is `Input.gyro`, which can be used to determine where approximately you are pointing. Use this information and the flight transponder data to compute your position relative to the aircraft. Obviously, this will be wildly inaccurate. But, as others suggested, you can gain additional accuracy by setting your virtual camera up as a Unity physical camera and matching it up with your real-world camera. From your camera footage, extract the clip space position of the aircraft using some kind of image recognition method (i.e. a `ComputeShader` retrieving the location of a small dark spot) and then use `Camera.ScreenPointToRay` of that position to get a vector towards where the airplane **should be** in the scene. Using this, correct your virtual user position in the 3D scene, such that the ray lines up with the vector from your virtual camera to the virtual aircraft.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do is to do 1:1 map of real world in your unity scene. For that you will need to read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/BestPracticeMakingBelievableVisuals1.html#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%201%20Unity%20unit,systems%20assume%20this%20unit%20size.) documentation. Basically 1 unit in unity is 1 meter. To make dimensions of 3D objects 1:1 to real life dimensions you will need to resize/change scale of those objects manually. Good Luck with that!

Comment: I don't want to map the size of physical objects to virtual ones. I want to map their location in the real world to a virtual scene.

Comment: then 1 meter in real world is 1 unit in unity (unity coordinates)

Answer (score -1):

If you want a virtual camera that is just like your physical one then there's toggle in "camera" component called "physical camera". There you can set it's sensor data and all that kind of stuff. If it's not it, I don't know.